# Como filtrar un array si el criterio de búsqueda esta incompleto

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un el siguiente array

```
const sitiosEcoturisticos = [
{
nombre: "parque el poblado",
municipio: "medellin",
departmento: "antioquia",
latitud: 5.25,
longitud: 10.5,
estrellas: 10,
},

{
nombre: "el coco",
municipio: "medellin",
departmento: "antioquia",
latitud: 5,
longitud: 10,
estrellas: 1,
},

{
nombre: "volcan",
municipio: "bello",
departmento: "antioquia",
latitud: 4,
longitud: 10,
estrellas: 5,
},
 ];
```

Tengo una función que hace un filtro donde KEY es el atributo y VALUE el valor que contiene dicho atributo y  funciona correctamente

```
const filtrarResultados = (key,value)=> {

  const result = sitiosEcoturisticos.filter(
  (sitios) => sitios[key] == value.toLowerCase()
  );

  console.log(result);
  };
```

Si la invoco y le paso por parámetros

```
filtrarResultados("municipio","medellin")
```

me retorna los 2 que array que tienen en su municipio el valor "medellin", mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que cuando le pase por parámetro aluna palabra incompleta aun asi me haga la búsqueda y me lo retorne  filtrarResultados("municipio","medel")

Comment: Para eso en lugar de usar == usa indexOf

Comment: @gabriel si tienes clara la respuesta, te animo a compartirla, así aumentas tu reputación y de paso empiezas a soltar las manos en la comunidad jeje ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso es posible usando indexOf.

Si quieres que lo detecte la palabra en cualquier lugar

```
const filtrarResultados = (key,value)=> {

  const result = 
  sitiosEcoturisticos.filter(
   (sitios) => sitios[key].indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0
  );

  console.log(result);
};
```

Pero si quieres que esté la palabra por obligacion en la el comienzo Seria haci

```
const filtrarResultados = (key,value)=> {

  const result = sitiosEcoturisticos.filter(
   (sitios) => sitios[key].indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) == 0
 );

  console.log(result);
 };
```

IndexOf muestra la posición donde aparece esta la palabra. Si no está en el string el te soltará -1

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar include sobre el texto:

```js
const sitiosEcoturisticos = [{
    nombre: "parque el poblado",
    municipio: "medellin",
    departmento: "antioquia",
    latitud: 5.25,
    longitud: 10.5,
    estrellas: 10,
  },

  {
    nombre: "el coco",
    municipio: "medellin",
    departmento: "antioquia",
    latitud: 5,
    longitud: 10,
    estrellas: 1,
  },

  {
    nombre: "volcan",
    municipio: "bello",
    departmento: "antioquia",
    latitud: 4,
    longitud: 10,
    estrellas: 5,
  },
];

const termino = "mede"
const r = sitiosEcoturisticos.filter(sitio => sitio.municipio.includes(termino))

console.log(r)
```